# Why this error coming when angular send data to spring boot backend?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

Receiving below warning in spring Terminal:

```
WARN 7260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.chamika.spire.demoapplication.Student com.chamika.spire.demoapplication.MainController.save(com.chamika.spire.demoapplication.Student)]
```

**My Spring boot Maincontroller.java code**

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  StudentService studentService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Student save(@RequestBody Student student) {

  return studentService.save(student);

  }
}
```

**My Angular student.service.ts code**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '../models/student'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const headeroption = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  url = 'http://localhost:8080/';
  student: Observable<Student[]>;


  save(newStudent: Student) {
    return this.http.post(this.url  + 'student', newStudent, headeroption);
  }
}
```

**My Angular addstudent.component.ts code**

```
import { Student } from './../../models/student';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from './../../services/student.service.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addstudent',
  templateUrl: './addstudent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addstudent.component.scss']
})
export class AddstudentComponent implements OnInit {

  student: Student = {
    id: null,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private studentService: StudentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.student = {
      id: null,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    }

  }

  addStudent(addStu: Student) {
    console.log("Went inside funtion");
    console.log(this.student);
    this.studentService.save(addStu).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.ngOnInit();
    });
  }

}
```

I post data using Postman and its worked perfectly.
but when i tried to send data using angular UI, its didn't work and receiving above error in spring terminal

Comment: Please add Student Object and JSON passed from UI.

Comment: Ok i added that codes

Comment: What is Output of console.log(this.student);  Also compare this output to JSON passed in Postman, YOu can inspect browser console to see what API is being passed.  Ctrl + Shift + I for windows

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting ?

Comment: @MyTwoCents console output is :  Object { id: "11", firstName: "TestFname", lastName: "TestLname" }

Comment: @Yogendra123  I mention the actual error above

Comment: Please share your model from java end as well.

Comment: Try my edit.  JSON.stringify(newStudent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say `Postman` is working fine and from your App it's not, something is wrong with Data you are sending in `API` call.

If you are using `Angular 4+` headers are optional

Try this

```
save(newStudent: Student) {
    return this.http.post(this.url  + 'student', JSON.stringify(newStudent) );
}
```

If this doesn't work you can inspect Browser console to see what value is passed in Request and its content-type and add here.

Something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwMua.png)

**Edit 1:**

Try this

```
  save(newStudent: Student) {
    return this.http.post(this.url  + 'student', JSON.stringify(newStudent), headeroption);
  }
```

**EDIT:2**

Based on screenshot looks like CORS issue as you are running UI on different port and Spring is running on a different port

Create a `WebMvcConfig` class like this to allow CrossOrigin

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS").allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Error received without headers : " org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported "

Comment: Error received with headers " Same previous error (Required request body is missing) "

Comment: This is my browser control window  " https://imgur.com/6yRHnBm "

Comment: How to add this WebMvcConfig  file to Java Jax-rs(jersy) program to allow CroosOrigin ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is showing as you are not sending the required request body properly. Your save method expecting a request body that has Student type. You can create a FormData object in your angular application and then append all the fields inside the FormData object, finally while sending the request to the spring backend bind the Formdata object name as student.